# Angular PrimeNG: p-table custom sorting function?

Tags: angular, sorting, primeng, primeng-datatable

I am using PrimeNG's p-table. in that the default sorting functionality is in ascending and descending order, like this

suppose we have a data on a column like this -

```
aaa
bbb
aaa
ccc
bbb
ccc
```

when we will apply sorting in ascending order it is showing like this -

```
aaa
aaa
bbb
bbb
ccc
ccc
```

and when we will apply sorting in descending order it is showing like this -

```
ccc
ccc
bbb
bbb
aaa
aaa
```

**but here I want a different sorting functionality like if we are sorting in ascending order it should come like this -**

```
aaa
aaa
ccc
ccc
bbb
bbb
```

here the ccc should come in middle and bbb should come at last

**and when we will apply sorting in descending order it should come like this -**

```
bbb
bbb
ccc
ccc
aaa
aaa
```

here the bbb should come at first and ccc should come in middle

here is my html -

```
<p-table #orderTable [value]="orderData"
       [rowHover]="true"
       [rows]="5"
       [scrollable]="true"
       [filterDelay]="0"
       [globalFilterFields]="['status']"
       class="borderless"
       (sortFunction)="customSort($event)" 
       [customSort]="true">

<ng-template pTemplate="colgroup" let-columns>
  <colgroup>
    <col [style.min-width]="'100px'" [style.width]="'100px'">
  </colgroup>
</ng-template>

<ng-template pTemplate="header">
  <tr>
    <th pSortableColumn="status">Status<p-sortIcon field="status"></p-sortIcon></th>
  </tr>
</ng-template>
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-order>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="hide-overflow-text">
        <button class=pill>{{order.status}}</button>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</ng-template>
```

here is the custom sorting function -

```
customSort(event: SortEvent) {
 event.data.sort((data1, data2) => {
  let value1 = data1[event.field];
  let value2 = data2[event.field];
  let result = null;

  if (value1 == null && value2 != null)
    result = -1;
  else if (value1 != null && value2 == null)
    result = 1;
  else if (value1 == null && value2 == null)
    result = 0;
  else if (typeof value1 === 'string' && typeof value2 === 'string') {
    result = value1.localeCompare(value2);
  }
  else
    result = (value1 < value2) ? -1 : (value1 > value2) ? 1 : 0;

  return (event.order * result);
});
```

}

Any idea what logic should I use for the custom sorting instead of using the ascending, descending order?

Comment: And what is your specific question?

Comment: What logic should I use for the sorting instead of using the ascending, descending order

Comment: Sorting is always comparing one (group of) item(s) to another. See: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sorting If you want to order in a different way you might want to look into adding additional info into your array that can be sorted.

Comment: Is this a different question from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72695900/angular-primeng-p-table-add-custom-sorting-function-to-specific-column and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72702886/angular-primeng-p-table-add-custom-sorting-function-with-multiple-values-to-a-s